# Row Space using a Vector Representation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification, vector-spaces

For the matrix N = $$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  1& 2 \\ 
 0&  1& 2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

determine the row space of N, writing in the form row(N) = {($x,y,z$) $\in \mathbb R^3$ |...}. Hence, write row(N) using a generic vector.

I know that N is in echelon form. I can write row(N) = span{$(1,1,2),(0,1,2)$}. I want to write in the form given, so I wrote row(N) = {($a,a+b,2a+2b$) $\in \mathbb R^3$ | $a,b \in \mathbb R$}.

I think this is correct ?

But I am unsure on how to write it using a generic vector. If it said generic vector$\mathbf{s}$, I would just write row(N) = span{$(1,1,2),(0,1,2)$}. These two vectors are linearly independent so I don't know what more I can do ?

Comment: I don't fully understand your request.  Yes, each way you have written the span so far is correct.  I will point out that if you were to perform row reduction first, you can have a simpler expression, here being $\{(a,b,2b)~:~a,b\in\Bbb R\}$.  I do not understand what you are referring to in the last paragraph except perhaps in reminding you that you can row reduce before representing in order to reduce potential redundancy and to possibly make the final representation cleaner.

Comment: @JMoravitz So you are saying reduce to reduced echelon form first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "row(N) = {($a,a+b,2a+2b$) $\in \mathbb R^3$ | $a,b \in \mathbb R$}" is correct, but "writing in the form row(N) = {($x,y,z$) $\in \mathbb R^3$ |...}" asks you to find an equation satisfied by $(x,y,z)$ iff there exists $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that
$$x=a,\quad y=a+b,\quad z=2a+2b.$$
For this, you have to *eliminate* the parameters $a,b.$ The equations above are equivalent to
$$a=x,\quad b=y-x,\quad z=2y,$$
hence
$$\operatorname{row}(N)=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid z=2y\}.$$

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for your help, that makes sense. So I presume this gives the same span but in the form they ask for. How would I write it using a "generic vector" though ?

Comment: I think that their phrase "generic vector" means nothing more than "writing in the form row(N) = {($x,y,z$) $\in \mathbb R^3$ | equation(s)}".

Comment: The equation(s) would be $z=2y$ then ?

Comment: Yes. And the fact that there is only one equation could be foreseen: the subspace is of codimension $3-2=1.$

Comment: I am confused because they asked for two forms. First in row(N) = {($x,y,z$) $\in \mathbb R^3$ |...}, and then write row(N) using a generic vector

Comment: I am not sure their 2 sentences should be interpreted like that. Imo they only reworded a single question.

Comment: The full question is: for the matrix N, determine the row space and write it as row(N) = {($x,y,z$) $\in \mathbb R^3$ |...}. Hence write row(N) using a generic vector.

Comment: Yes, I read it at the beginning of your post. These are the 2 sentences I was talking about. But maybe @JMoravitz's guess was right and the second sentence asks you to write $\operatorname{row}(N)=\{(x,y,2y)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}.$

Comment: Thanks, all makes sense. Thank you.